# Deploy and manage workload both on local machine and cloud

Tags: docker, kubernetes, devops, amazon-eks, k3s

How can I  can deploy and manage workload both on cloud and local machine or split workload between on-premise and cloud. Here you can assume on-premise to be your local laptop.

I want a method /software /platform which can run Kubernetes pods/workload both on local machine and cloud.

I found AWS outpost as one of them but I think it works only on-premise. It cannot deploy workload on AWS and also very less information is available about it .

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for k8s hybrid cloud mechanism. you can check for google anthos, nutanix etc